# Hive - Create dataset which replaces all values with most common

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I need to create a dataset that contains the same rows as the source table but has the date of birth replaced with the most common date of birth value found for that person. If there is a tie then the most recent date should be used.

input

```
id  first_name  last_name  dob       date
---------------------------------------------
1   john        doe        06/11/85  01/01/17
2   john        doe        06/11/86  01/01/17
3   john        doe        06/11/86  01/01/17
4   jane        doh        01/06/87  01/01/17
5   jane        doh        01/01/80  01/02/17
```

output

```
1 john doe 06/11/86 01/01/17
2 john doe 06/11/86 01/01/17
3 john doe 06/11/86 01/01/17
4 jane doh 01/01/80 01/01/17
5 jane doh 01/01/80 01/02/17
```

John Doe is updated 06/11/86 (most common). jane doh is updated to 01/01/80 (tie breaker broken).

My most recent attempt based on a similar example:

```
SELECT a.id, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.date, b.id  FROM 
(SELECT first_name, last_name,dob,count(*) FROM table group by first_name, last_name,dob having count(*) in 
(SELECT max(total) AS freq FROM 
(SELECT first_name, last_name, dob, count(*) AS total FROM table group by first_name, last_name, dob) 
AS test_temp group by first_name, last_name)
) a   join (select * FROM table) b on (a.id = b.id)
```

I don't want just a solution but also an explanation I can learn from.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT a.id, a.first_name, a.last_name, b.dob, a.date
 FROM table a 
 JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id, first_name, last_name, dob, count(dob) AS cnt 
       FROM table ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1) b 
 ON (a.first_name=b.first_name) AND (a.last_name=b.last_name)`

I would try this. I joined the base table with a subselect in order to get the most common dob. With `ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1` I made shure to get the most common dob without getting into trouble in case `max(count(dob))`is not unique . then i just joined that dob to every record with the same `firt_name` and `last_name`. I hope that helpes you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `first_value()` function to assign the date of birth, with no `JOIN`s:

```
  select t.id, t.first_name, t.last_name,
         first_value(dob) over (partition by first_name, last_name
                                order by dob_cnt desc, date desc
                                rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                               ) as dob_imputed
  from (select t.*,
               count(*) over (partition by first_name, last_name, dob) as dob_cnt
        from t
       ) t
```